# Mass of text, cherry pick email addresses

Tags: php, regex

I have a large file full of text and in there are some email addresses.

Which php regular expression function would return an array of email addresses it could find?

So far I have

```
<?php

$pattern = "/^[^@]*@[^@]*\.[^@]*$/";

if ($handle = opendir('files')) {

/* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
   preg_match($pattern, $file, $matches);

   echo count($matches);
   foreach ($matches as $email) {
     echo "$email <br />";
   }
}

closedir($handle);
}
```

but it returns no results

Comment: Your regex will match "Twitter-style" names at the end of a sentence with a trailing space or even punctuation (eg "Hey @azz0r."). Edit: Looking again, it will even match at the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code, that works perfect, thanks everyone :)

```
<?php

set_time_limit('0');
$pattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$";

if ($handle = opendir('files')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        $content = file_get_contents('files/'.$file);
        preg_match_all('#([^@]+@[-a-z0-9.]+)#', $content, $matches);
        echo count($matches[1]).' - '.$file.'<br />';
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Worthy of note, after scouring google for regex, with my script, here are the patterns I collected:

```
    $pattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$";
$pattern = "/([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@([ ]+|)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)/i";
$pattern = '#([^@]+@[-a-z0-9.]+)#';
$pattern = '(^|\s|<)[a-zA-Z]([.+-]?\w+)+@(\w{2,}\.)+\w{2,5}($|\s|>)';
$pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$";
$pattern = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
$pattern = "(^|\s|<)[a-zA-Z]([.+-]?\w+)+@(\w{2,}\.)+\w{2,5}($|\s|>)";
```

The best pattern is:

```
$pattern = "/([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@([ ]+|)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)/i";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$file = file_get_contents('filename.txt');
if(preg_match_all('#([^@]+@[-a-z0-9.]+)#',$file,$matches)) {
  $emails = $matches[1]; // array of all the emails in the file.
}
```

The regex is simplified and not a 100% RFC822 implementation.

**EDIT:**

The [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) function returns the **filename** on success not the file contents. You can try doing:

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
   $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
   if(preg_match_all('#([^@]+@[-a-z0-9.]+)#', $file_content, $matches)) {

     echo count($matches[1]);
     foreach ($matches[1] as $email) {
       echo "$email <br />";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see three problems:

1. In regular expressions, `^` means the start of a line (or string) and `$` means the end of a line (or string), that is probably why the pattern you are using doesn't work. It would only find an email address on a line by itself.
2. You are passing the file's name to `preg_match`; it is expecting a string to be searched. You need to call `file_get_contents` or something like it to pass the file's text to the function.
3. You need to use `preg_match_all` to find more than one match at a time, if there are multiple addresses in each file.

Answer (score 0):

Read through

- [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

You can adapt the Regex given there or any other Regex you can find on the web for this purpose and then simply do a

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $someString, $matches);
```

`$matches` will then contain whatever was found for the Regex you used.

In case your file is too big to be loaded into memory, consider iterating over it with [fgets()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of sites talking about regexes for email addresses. [This one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) in particular is quite expansive.

The short answer is that the definition of a 'valid' email address does not lend itself to a simple regex. Most practical regular expressions for email addresses trade completeness for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(^|\s|<)[a-zA-Z]([.+-]?\w+)+@(\w{2,}\.)+\w{2,5}($|\s|>)
```

Add other possible delimiters to the starting and ending groups `^|\s|<`