# How can I prevent someone sending email addresses in message?

Tags: php, email, filter

I want to filter those messages ( a long text string ) if it contains any personal information ( email ) in PHP.
Is there a built-in function in PHP or if anybody has experienced filtering like this, I would be thankful with.

Thanks !

Comment: Is this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424659/check-if-a-string-contains-an-email-address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mass of text, cherry pick email addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335124/mass-of-text-cherry-pick-email-addresses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search and replace emails with another string:

`$str = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/', '[censored]', $str);`